# .htaccess is working in localhost but not in server?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess code that working in localhost but not working in server

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What is the solution?

Comment: is the mod_rewrite module activated?

Comment: Maybe `AllowOverride` is `none`?

Comment: my server is shared hosting.. So i can't access mod_rewrite module

Comment: Check whether your host suppport htaccess

Comment: of course it working. I tested it with another .htaccess file..

Comment: Maybe the location of htaccess file is wrong.

Comment: Please show me the folder path of the .htaccess in local and server

Comment: Try to delete RewriteBase /

Comment: Tried but not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code , I am using a function called 
      `run()` 
(which is a user defined function)
for checking a particular condition. When disabling that function everything working fine. Then I changed that function name to another name that time also works. I don't know why `run()` not working in server. But now my problem solved